# How to add ACF image field to WP admin table column of custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created an ACF image field "cat_thumb" to a custom taxonomy "linen_category". The image field was set to return array value.

I have got some codes below which can be put in function.php file, but it doesn't work. The term thumbnail image won't be showed in admin column.

```
/*
 * Add ACF thumbnail columns to custom taxonomies
 */
function add_thumbnail_columns($columns) {
    $columns['linen_thumbnail'] = __('Thumbnail');
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-linen_category_columns', 'add_thumbnail_columns');

/*
 * Output ACF thumbnail columns
 */
function thumbnail_columns_content($column_name) {
    if ($column_name == 'cat_thumb') {
        $term = get_queried_object();
        $linen_thumbnail_var = get_field('cat_thumb', $term);
        echo '<img src="'.$linen_thumbnail_var['url'].'" width="60" />';
    }
}
add_filter('manage_linen_category_custom_column' , 'thumbnail_columns_content' , 10 , 1);
```

I have worked on this for over a week, but still can't figure out how to do. Please help me out, thanks.

Comment: I'll answer to my question below.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I have figured it out and got the final solution after reading many many articles and documents.

Here is my code

```
/**
 * Add ACF thumbnail columns to Linen Category custom taxonomy
 */
function add_thumbnail_columns($columns) {
    $columns['linen_thumbnail'] = __('Thumbnail');
    // Enable the single line of code below if you want the Thumbnail at the end.
    //return $columns;

    // Code below will make the Thumbnail in the front.
    // Code start
    $new = array();
    foreach($columns as $key => $value) {
        if ($key=='name') // Put the Thumbnail column before the Name column
            $new['linen_thumbnail'] = 'Thumbnail';
        $new[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $new;
    // Code end
}
add_filter('manage_edit-linen_category_columns', 'add_thumbnail_columns');

/**
 * Output ACF thumbnail content in Linen Category custom taxonomy columns
 */
function thumbnail_columns_content($content, $column_name, $term_id) {
    if ('linen_thumbnail' == $column_name) {
        $term = get_term($term_id);
        $linen_thumbnail_var = get_field('cat_thumb', $term);
        $content = '<img src="'.$linen_thumbnail_var['url'].'" width="60" />';
        }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('manage_linen_category_custom_column' , 'thumbnail_columns_content' , 10 , 3);
```

Reference:

- [Plugin API/Filter Reference/manage $taxonomy id columns | WordPress
  Document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$taxonomy_id_columns)
- [Function Reference/get term | WordPress Document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term)
- [Adding fields to a taxonomy term | ACF Document](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)
- [Image | ACF Document](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)
- [WordPress Sortable Admin Columns for Custom Posts | Acticle](https://www.ractoon.com/2016/11/wordpress-custom-sortable-admin-columns-for-custom-posts/)
- [Change the order of columns for a custom post type on the admin list
  page | StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101728/change-the-order-of-columns-for-a-custom-post-type-on-the-admin-list-page)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from:

```
$linen_thumbnail_var = get_field('cat_thumb', $term);
```

to

```
$linen_thumbnail_var = get_field('cat_thumb', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
```

This will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. But I have figured out the problem and tested to get the final solution after reading many many articles and documents.

Comment: Seems get_queried_object() only works on Archive page? Anyway get_term($term_id) works.